# Extension Admin page "404 not found"

Tags: adminhtml, supee-6788, routing

Installed update for an extension (EmailDirect, after running patch 6788) successfully on local environment, but when uploaded to testing server it throws a "404 page not found".

I even reinstalled a local copy from GIT, so both local and testing servers have the same code. Flushed cache several times and nothing, keeps missing the page only on testing server.

I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724995/magento-404-on-admin-page accepted answer. If the page is ok then it shows the stacktrace, but if it's 404 it doesn't.

So i basically don't know why it's throwing a "404 not found" or how to debug it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you log out of the admin panel then log back in again? Magento needs to update the Access Control List (ACL) to grant you access to the new functionality, and that's how it does it.

Comment: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details Note the `adminhtml.xml` changes. Make sure the modules code is updated properly.

Comment: Check if you have same admin configuration for routing compatibility in your installation on both local and testing server.

Comment: Did you created a Folder inside controllers/Adminhtml/EmailDirect ? Try changing EmailDirect to Emaildirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

As Natalie said, the problem was "Try changing EmailDirect to Emaildirect". For some reason the uppercase was working on a vagrant-windows environment but not on linux server or vagrant-mac environment.

Comment: Glad it help you. I almost died when I find out that ONE letter was all the problem.